# Count Days between Dates Swift (Considering what may be tomorrow.)

Tags: swift, date

I have this code:

```
extension Date {
    /// From today to self
    /// - Returns: number of days.
    func getDaysUntil() -> Int? {        
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: self).day
    }
}
```

I need everything to be considered in terms of EST.  So regardless of which time zone we are in, everything should be regarded as EST.

I am having a problem when comparing today with tomorrow.

So take the following case:

**Date() // (now):**: June 15.
**self (compare to):**: June 16.

Regardless the time of day today, I want to say that it's 1 day until the comparison date (self).

So, if it's 11:59pm and the comparison date (self) is 12:01am, I want the result to be 1 day.  If it's 12:01am and the comparison date (self) is 11:59pm, I still want the comparison result to be 1.

As it is, no matter what I do, when we get to those extreme edges, the date calculation is off by 1, one way or the other.

Also, this isn't *just* a today vs. tomorrow issue.  The correct count should be the result (considering the today/tomorrow conundrum) for any date.

Is there some fancy trick, or does anyone have any suggestion how we could accomplish this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a default "don't care" time calendrical calculation what you need is to use noon time. Check WWDC session 227 [Solutions to Common Date and Time Challenges](https://docs.huihoo.com/apple/wwdc/2013/session_227__solutions_to_common_date_and_time_challenges.pdf). Check the "Midnight" part and what is said about why people should NOT use midnight.

```
extension Calendar {
    static let iso8601 = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    /// From today's noon to self's noon
    /// - Returns: number of days.
    var daysFromToday: Int {
        Calendar.iso8601.dateComponents([.day], from: Date().noon, to: noon).day!
    }
    /// Noon time
    /// - Returns: same date at noon
    var noon: Date {
        Calendar.iso8601.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)!
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let yesterday = DateComponents(calendar: .iso8601, year: 2022, month: 5, day: 2, hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59).date!

yesterday.daysFromToday  // -1
```

Comment: This looks great, thanks!  I'll implement tomorrow and if all works, I'll give you the upvote and the checkmark.  Cheers! 

Comment: For some reason when I compare anything between 12am and 1am it will result in +1 extra day.  Everything else from 1am to 11:59pm gives me what I would expect.

Comment: If you need a different timezone (other than the devices current timezone) you will need to create a custom calendar with the desired timezone and use it instead of the default iso8601

Comment: Ah my date string was off by one timezone.